# Batch Replace Multiple Texts in a file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I need to replace multiple different instances of text in a file using a .bat.

(Note: SQF is just a server config file, Encoding is not an issue)

I have tried:

```
powershell -Command "(gc Structures.sqf) -replace 'WOOD_WALL', 'CINDERBLOCK_WALL' | Out-File BrickMe.sqf"

powershell -Command "(gc Structures.sqf) -replace 'e614ee17-4467-4d51-a3f2-d4faa61de89e', 'a59f5b71-2b9a-45a2-85bb-ec29a47f78aa' | Out-File BrickMe.sqf"

powershell -Command "(gc Structures.sqf) -replace 'Wood Wall', 'Cinderblock Wall' | Out-File BrickMe.sqf"
```

But it only performs the last command. Eg. WOOD_WALL remains.

And

```
sed -e "s/WOOD_WALL/CINDERBLOCK_WALL/" -e "s/Wood Wall/Cinderblock Wall/" <Structures.sqf>BrickMe.sqf
```

Just creates an empty file called BrickMe.sqf

I have also tried a VBScript to no avail. I would rather keep it able to run on any Windows machine provided the code can handle the file size but I don't know how to replace multiple instances of different text without repeating the whole command and taking a long time.

I have also looked at this http://www.dostips.com/?t=batch.findandreplace
But was unsure of where to put my "WOOD_WALL" instances and my file names.

I have found heaps of results on google for replacing 1 piece of text in multiple files but hardly anything on replacing multiple texts in 1 file.

*The Story:

I am running an Arma 3 server and have built a wooden admin base in game that I wish to convert to a cinderblock base. I have done this before but only manually by replacing the Instance Name, Instance_ID and Entity Name. I would like to do it using a batch file if possible and upload it to `http://www.exilemod.com` to help other admins. The files are usually no larger then 15 Megabytes in size.*

I'm pretty awesome with Windows batch files but am new to PowerShell.

Comment: I have also seen this but I don't understand how to run it from a batch file:                                                                                       $filename="textfile.txt"
$outputfile="$filename" + ".out"

Get-Content $filename | Foreach-object {
    $_ -replace '\[', 'a' `
       -replace '\]', 'o' `
       -replace '\|', 'u'
} | Set-Content $outputfile

Comment: Are you asking about a batch file or Powershell? They're not the same thing, and the tag definitions are entirely different. You're looking for one or the other. You're either looking for a batch file that runs via cmd, or a Powershell script that runs in Powershell. Pick one, and then correct your tags and question appropriately. And please stop tag spamming. Don't grab every tag that sounds familiar without reading the tag definition first.

Comment: Also, how are we supposed to tell you how to replace the text when we know absolutely nothing about the content?

Comment: I am after a batch file. From what I understood you can run PowerShell commands through windows batch files. Is this not correct?

Comment: Why does the content matter? It's just a text file.

Comment: *you can run Powershell commands* Yes, that's true, but then the commands would be Powershell code for replacing text, not batch commands. And where the content is in the line is extremely relevant in answering a question about replacing it. As I asked, please [edit] your question to be **specific** about what you're asking, remove the tag(s) that are not relevant, and include the content of the text you're trying to replace.

Comment: The content makes a big difference, because it's a vastly different task to replace `replaceme` at the beginning of the line than it is to replace `this is a bunch of other stuff around replaceme the text I want to replace`, and any answer would need to be aware of what **specifically** you're trying to do. I'd strongly suggest you read through [ask].

Comment: Okay well I don't know anything about powershell, I only tried doing it with powershell but it didn't work. I don't really care which way I do it as long as file paths don't have to be changed in the code everytime someone wants to use it, which is why I put powershell and cmd in the tags. Here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ktjn5p4gixh3hse/Structures.sqf?dl=0

Answer (score 4):

It's no wonder that your actions are not successfull.

You always take the original input file, perform actions and save to the same output file this way overwriting the previous action.

For better understanding the PowerShell part broken up:

```
(gc Structures.sqf) -replace 'WOOD_WALL', 'CINDERBLOCK_WALL' `
                    -replace 'e614ee17-4467-4d51-a3f2-d4faa61de89e', 
                             'a59f5b71-2b9a-45a2-85bb-ec29a47f78aa' `
                    -replace 'Wood Wall', 'Cinderblock Wall' | 
 Out-File BrickMe.sqf
```

As the `-replace` operator is RegEx based the 1st and 3rd replace can be joined by:

- placing a character class `[_ ]` underscore or space inside
- a capture group `([_ ])` and
- using the capture group in the replacement string `$1`

```
(gc Structures.sqf) -replace 'WOOD([_ ])WALL', 'CINDERBLOCK$1WALL' `
                    -replace 'e614ee17-4467-4d51-a3f2-d4faa61de89e', 
                             'a59f5b71-2b9a-45a2-85bb-ec29a47f78aa' | 
Out-File BrickMe.sqf
```

All this wrapped again in a cmd line:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "(gc Structures.sqf) -replace 'WOOD([_ ])WALL', 'CINDERBLOCK$1WALL' -replace 'e614ee17-4467-4d51-a3f2-d4faa61de89e','a59f5b71-2b9a-45a2-85bb-ec29a47f78aa'|Out-File BrickMe.sqf"
```

Comment: AHH BINGO! That's what I was after. Thank you. :)

Comment: That did the trick. I thought my command would stack the saves, So save first change then re-open, perform the second change and re-save, keeping the progress. Kudo's to you.

Comment: If you find an answer helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)